# Node Sass could not find a binding for W64-bit and Node.js 6.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack

I'm receiving this error message when I'm trying to process `scss` files. I'm using `webpack sass-loader`.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/scss/application.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules
-x64-48\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was up since I had installed Node.js 7.x previously, and `node-sass` was build on Node.js 7.x version.

So:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

It's been solved.